How to access Lucide Icons categories 'lucide-vue-next' package?
I see in showcase there are categories which I'd love to use in my icon picker. Is it possible somehow to access them? Or maybe somebody can suggest a solution for such case. Generally I'd like to show more relevant category first and use it in the search.
Documentation: https://github.com/lucide-icons/lucide
